# Flutter - display image from storage and data from db

Tags: mysql, flutter, amazon-s3, storage

I'm trying to do an app in flutter that display some info about a restaurant from a DB, and for each restaurant an image of it. How can I do that? I was trying to use s3 from aws to store the images but I don't know how to save the reference of that image into my db without make the access to the bucket public.
Can anyone helps me please?

Answer (score 0):

There has some way to do this. You can simply use this package which I am mention below:
https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Or you can use the Image widget which provided my flutter. I share some simple code:

NB: If you using asset images then use asset.
`Image.asset('assets/images/background_image.jpg',fit: BoxFit.cover,height: 400,)`

`Image.network('imageUrl',fit: BoxFit.cover,height: 400,)`

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, is there a way to do it using s3? Becouse to obtain an url from s3 you have to make a request with authentication and I don't know if there is the right method to do it

Comment: You should make the bucket public, one way or another you need to access the files, and sharing the authentication keys *inside* your app is a big no-no. Another approach might be writing a separate backend that holds the auth keys, and then fetches the images from the S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

u can use cached_network_image plugin

Here is package link
https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

use this widget like this:-

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: // place holder image
        errorWidget: Container(), // use container or any other widget to avoid cross line issue in image
     ),
```

Comment: thanks for giving advice to handle eroor i when i use network image it show cross red line some times it save my time